# Remove HTML tags from a String in Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, innerhtml

I’ve been trying to achieve this for a while, I have a string which contains a lot of HTML tags in it which is in some encoded form 
Like & lt; and & gt; (without the spaces) in between the string.
Can anyone assist me in removing those tags so that I can get a plain string?

Comment: @feeela We are not in javascript here though

Comment: @feeela This won’t work in Dart I guess.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html or https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_webview_plugin might help for this task

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer  finally I achieved this using the HTML package.

Comment: That was quick. How did you do it? I wasn't sure if the `html` package supports modifying (never used it). Perhaps you can answer your question with some example code?

Comment: Sure! Just give me a second, it’s hard to write code on phone.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

Finally I achieved this using the html package

Here’s how I did it

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';


//here goes the function 
String _parseHtmlString(String htmlString) {
final document = parse(htmlString);
final String parsedString = parse(document.body.text).documentElement.text;

return parsedString;
}
```

I don’t know if there is any cleaner way to do this but this one worked for me.

Comment: It is not built in, perhaps some of your packages already included it? https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/html#-readme-tab-

Comment: use this package to import html/parser https://pub.dev/packages/html

Answer (score 71):

You can simply use RegExp without 3rd Lib for remove tag (

</>)

```
String removeAllHtmlTags(String htmlText) {
    RegExp exp = RegExp(
      r"<[^>]*>",
      multiLine: true,
      caseSensitive: true
    );

    return htmlText.replaceAll(exp, '');
  }
```

Comment: Regex is never the way to work with HTML https://regex101.com/r/HukWkb/1


When used on a string `'<a title="1 < 3, but 3 > 2">Don't use regex to parse HTML</a>'`, `'2">Don't use regex to parse HTML'` will be left after replacing instead of `'Don't use regex to parse HTML'`

Answer (score 38):

The `intl` package provides a method `stripHtmlIfNeeded` to strip the HTML tags from the string.

The `Bidi` class under this package provides the utility method for working with the bidirectional text.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Bidi.stripHtmlIfNeeded("<p>Hello World</p>")
```

If you don't want to use the whole package just for this function, below is the method implementation:

```
static String stripHtmlIfNeeded(String text) {
  return text.replaceAll(RegExp(r'<[^>]*>|&[^;]+;'), ' ');
}
```

Documentation: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/Bidi/stripHtmlIfNeeded.html

Answer (score 2):

By just using

```
import ‘package:html/parser.dart’;
```

will get a problem, for those strings that includes `<br>` and `<p>` tags. Paragraph info is missing. May first replace `<br>` to `<p>`, then get List:

```
import ‘package:html/parser.dart’  as dom; 

htmlString = '<p> first ... line.<br>second.....line.<p>'; 

List<String> cleanStrings = new List<String>();
List<dom.Element> ps = parse(htmlString.replaceAll('<br>', '</p><p>'))).querySelectorAll('p');
if (ps.isNotEmpty) ps.forEach((f) {
  (f.text != '') cleanStrings.add(f.text);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution if using flutter web or can't import the parser for any reason and it's configurable.

```
  String formatHtmlString(String string) {
      return string
          .replaceAll("\n\n", "<p>") // Paragraphs
          .replaceAll("\n", "<br>") // Line Breaks
          .replaceAll("\"", "&quot;") // Quote Marks
          .replaceAll("'", "&apos;") // Apostrophe
          .replaceAll(">", "&lt;") // Less-than Comparator (Strip Tags)
          .replaceAll("<", "&gt;") // Greater-than Comparator (Strip Tags)
          .trim(); // Whitespace
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to Decode the HTML content to String then Follow this step:

1. Add this plugin to `pubspec.yaml` =>
   [HTML Parser - Dart Library](https://pub.dev/packages/html)

2. Then in your code add this Line =>

   `String htmlText = parse("String with HTML tags").body!.text`

Answer (score -2):

3 steps

first, add this to your "pubspec.yaml" file

> dependencies: 
>   flutter_html: ^0.8.2

second, import to your dart file

> import 'package:flutter_html_view/flutter_html_view.dart';

3rd, simply use

> HtmlView(data: "Your Html Data"),

Comment: I believe the question was about turning html into string with tags removed, not about displaying a formatted HTML?