# Dart / Flutter - Is there anyway to get the innerText for a block of HTML like in javascript?

Tags: html, flutter, dart, innertext

Is there anyway to get the inner text of a block of HTML code? I can display it but searched for ways but there doiesn't seem to be a easy way to get the inner text(i.e. strip all tags) like you can in javascript.
I am using flutter_html: ^1.0.2.

Example:

```
Container(
   child: Html(data: "<p>Hello world!</p>")
)
```

Above code will display "Hello world!", but there's no way to extract that into a variable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up finding the answer to my own question. Hope this help those who also searching:

[Remove HTML tags from a String in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593790/remove-html-tags-from-a-string-in-dart)