# Share Html String in Flutter using Share plugin

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement the share feature in my App and I am sending successfully but now the problem is, All the sharing content is with HTML tags so,
How can I share without HTML tags?

```
void _share(int index) {
    try {
      Share.share(
        _popularList[index]
                .details!
                .replaceAll('<li>', '->  ')
                .replaceAll('</li>', '.')
                .replaceAll('<ul>', '')
                .replaceAll('</ul>', '')
                .replaceAll('&nbsp;', '')
                .replaceAll('<p>', '')
                .replaceAll('<h1>', '')
                .replaceAll('<h2>', '')
                .replaceAll('<h3>', '')
                .replaceAll('<em>', '')
                .replaceAll('<b>', '')
                .replaceAll('<img>', '')
                .replaceAll('<a>', '')
                .replaceAll('</h1>', '')
                .replaceAll('</h2>', '')
                .replaceAll('</h3>', '')
                .replaceAll('</em>', '')
                .replaceAll('</b>', '')
                .replaceAll('</img>', '')
                .replaceAll('</a>', '')
                .replaceAll('</p>', '')
                .replaceAll('<strong>', '')
                .replaceAll('</strong>', ''),
        subject: _popularList[index].name!,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print('error: $e');
    }
  }
```

For now, I am trying this but this is not right for some time.

And I am using Flutter Html plugin for getting Data from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ReqExp

```
string.replaceAll("(?s)<(\\w+)\\b[^<>]*>.*?</\\1>", "");
```

You can also use this package https://pub.dev/packages/html
with that code:

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart';

String _parseHtmlString(String htmlString) {
    final document = parse(htmlString);
    final String parsedString = parse(document.body.text).documentElement.text;

    return parsedString;
}
```

I heard that the second solution doesn't always work so you might wanna research yourself. The second snipped is from this post: [Remove HTML tags from a String in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51593790/remove-html-tags-from-a-string-in-dart)

If you want a different way let me know

Update:
This should also work:

```
import 'package:html/parser.dart' show parse;
import 'package:html/dom.dart';

main() {
  var document = parse(
      '<body>Hello world! <a href="www.html5rocks.com">HTML5 rocks!');
  print(document.outerHtml);
}
```

Comment: Can I also limit the String length? means I want only 10 String then What should I use?

Comment: Could you collaborate what you mean?

Comment: I mean, I have 1000 words of String and I want select/share only 500 words then What properties/function should I use?